# Recorded Video playing without sound 

Tags: android, media-player, video-capture

I have followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107270/Recording-and-Playing-Video-on-Android) to record the video. I have used the following coding to play the recorded Video..

> url = "file:///mnt/sdcard/CaptureVideo/1510402819.3gpp"

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
startActivity(i);
```

i have tried with mp4 and mp3 format still could not hear the sound. . .

**NOTE:
    if i am playing the recorded video directly not able to hear sound..** 
Any one help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the AudioSource and Audio Encoder as follows,

```
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Intent movieIntent = new Intent();
movieIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
movieIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(movieIntent);
```